# Convert flask application to django

Tags: django

I am trying re-write an application in Django which was earlier in written in Flask. The issue I am facing is there are some operation which are performed globally in Flask app and then when someone invokes a url a particular function is invoked which uses the operations performed globally. I am not sure how to transfer the operations which are performed globally in Flask into django. The url specific function I know can be invoked through views.py and urls.py but I am not sure how to do the global operation in Django.

Answer (score 0):

In Django 1.7 and later, the standard place to run code when an app is loaded in the app config's [`ready()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready) method.

Comment: No, you need to create a custom [`AppConfig`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/applications/#configuring-applications) for your app, and override the `ready` method.